# Converting Svg with base64 encoded png in it

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a Svg file which has a base64 encoded png in it.
Im trying to convert the file from svg to png using Imagemagick.
The problem being that the Svg converts (all the pure svg elements ie. text and such) but the png in the svg disappears.

Originaly i had alot of params added to the conversion but when i realized it wasn't working i striped it down to just this command:

```
convert /www/data/svg/201.svg /www/data/png/201.png
```

Original SVG:

[201.svg](http://dwit.se/201.svg)

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works for me with RSVG & MSVG protocols. What version of IM are you using, and how did you install the SVG delegates?

Comment: @emcconville: Thanks for your response!
I'm currently using this version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10.
SVG delegates: "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i".
Appriciate any help.

Comment: That is an ancient version - you will almost certainly need to update it to get this working.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Thank you for the feedback, i have now updated the version and it now works (almost). The png inside the svg is verry blurry but i guess that is some setting i need to adjust.
Thanks for the help!